# Magento2 override customer name.phtml plugin, but it was not display, Pls help to check any wrong in this? Thanks

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to override Magento2 Customer module firstname + lastname to lastname + firstname, I don't want to modify M2 orignal files，so made this plugin，but it wasn't desplay, Pls help to check any wrong about this, Thanks.

1：registration.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magecn_ChineseName',
    __DIR__
);
```

2: etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magecn\ChineseName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3: etc/frontend/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name">
        <plugin name="ChineseNameFieldsTemplate" type="Magecn\ChineseName\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget\Name"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

4:Plugin/Customer/Block/Widget/Name.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magecn\ChineseName\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name as Subject;

/**
 * Use name widget for chinese name.
 */
class Name
{
    /**
     * Substitute default template.
     *
     * @param Subject $subject
     * @param string $template
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeSetTemplate(Subject $subject, string $template)
    {
        if ($template === 'Magento_Customer::widget/name.phtml') {
            return ['Magecn_ChineseName::customer/widget/name.phtml'];
        }
        return [$template];
    }
}
```

5:view/frontend/templates/customer/widget/name.phtml

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name $block */

/*
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->toHtml() ?>

For checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml:

<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')
   ->setObject($block->getAddress())
   ->setFieldIdFormat('shipping:%s')
   ->setFieldNameFormat('shipping[%s]')
   ->toHtml() ?>
*/

$prefix = $block->showPrefix();
$middle = $block->showMiddlename();
$suffix = $block->showSuffix();
?>
<?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
<div class="field required fullname <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getContainerClassName()) ?>">
    <label for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <fieldset class="fieldset fieldset-fullname">
        <div class="fields">
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($prefix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-prefix<?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' required' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('prefix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('prefix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('prefix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> >
                        <?php foreach ($block->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getPrefix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('lastname')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('lastname')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('lastname')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php if ($middle): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $block->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field field-name-middlename<?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' required' : '' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('middlename')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('middlename')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('middlename')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename')) ?>" <?= $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' data-validate="{required:true}"' : '' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field field-name-firstname required">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('firstname')) ?>"
                       name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('firstname')) ?>"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('firstname')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname')) ?>" <?php if ($block->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') == 'required-entry') echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php if ($suffix): ?>
        <div class="field field-name-suffix<?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' required' ?>">
            <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?php if ($block->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('suffix')) ?>"
                            name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('suffix')) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('suffix')) ?>"
                            class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix')) ?>" <?php if ($block->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($block->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option) ?>"<?php if ($block->getObject()->getSuffix() == $_option): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_option)) ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (($prefix || $middle || $suffix) && !$block->getNoWrap()): ?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: find the bug, etc/module.xml <module name="Magecn\ChineseName" setup_version="1.0.0"> was wrong, should be <module name="Magecn_ChineseName" setup_version="1.0.0">